# Holes drilled in driver side Door Jamb?

Tags: chrysler, door, body, van

I recently bought a used 2017 Chrysler Pacifica van.  One day when I was getting into the driver seat, I noticed two holes that appeared to have been drilled into the door jamb of the driver door:

[image: door holes]

None of the other doors appear to have these holes.  What could be the reason for these holes? I was wondering if the vehicle was in a previous accident, or had body damage that for some reason required these holes to perform a repair, but I can't tell for sure.  It wasn't disclosed to me at purchase time that the vehicle was involved in any sort of accident.  The only other thing that might indicate some sort of repair, is there are a bunch of small dents on the bottom of the door frame as well.

[image: dents]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They only reason I can come up with why those holes would be there is for [paintless dent repair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paintless_dent_repair). Paintless dent repair is a process by which you manipulate the metal from inside a panel (such as the door) by sticking steel rods there and pressing outwards on the panel where the dent is at. These dents are of the type like a door ding or a pinpoint dent. The kind where the dent is VERY minor and where no paint is disturbed. In order to get to those dents they ingress through some kind of a hole. A lot of paintless dent repair people will use holes which already exist. In your case, it appears they drilled holes in there for the repair, but didn't repair the repair holes. Least they could have done is put some plugs in there.

Comment: I'm convinced this is the reason. After reading your answer, I watched some paintless dent repair videos and its looking like that is probably what they did. I guess my door was dented at some point and that's how they fixed it. I'll probably get some silicone to fill the holes.

Comment: Put some rust converter on the holes to prevent rust, then put some silicone in to plug them. Sounds like they put a *lot of holes* in there to fix things.

Comment: These are the only 2 holes *that I know of* at least.  One of them isn't even all the way through - they probably stopped drilling after realizing they needed to move lower.